# making subheaders inside a table in adf using af:column separateRows

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

i have a requirement in which i have to break a table in two parts like

[image: table design requirement]

Advised not to use style class

I have a option attribute of `separateRows af:column` . Please share sample code for `separateRows af:column` 
another option we are considering is using `styleClass="#{row.dataRow?'':'AFTableCellSubtotal'}"`